# How to do a Unit Test for the binary method?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I need at least three unit tests for the binary method. So far, this is what I have.

```
public class Test {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    @Test
    public void testBinarySearch(){
        assertEquals(0, Arrays.binarySearch(a, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: check size and/or null?

Answer (score 1):

You can add 2 checks for non available values, one for higher and lower. Binary search gives expected place for given element but in -ve sign.

```
assertEquals(-6, Arrays.binarySearch(a, 555));
assertEquals(-1, Arrays.binarySearch(a, 0));
```